# decrease polygon count in Maya

Tags: 3d, models, polygon, maya

I'm making models for games. In 3ds Max there was "polygon cruncher" plugin for reducing number of polygons. 
Is there something similar for Maya? Or is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - in Maya go to the Polygon menu then you should see a 'Reduce' option with a box that opens a sub-menu with a set of extra options to give you advanced control over what you reduce (i.e preserve hard edges etc )

HTH